# Why won't my controller recognize this array that is defined in services.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Going off of the concept that static data should be stored as a service and not in the controller, I have moved the data from controller.js to services.js but it no longer displays in the ng-repeat like it did when it was in the controller.

```
//services.js

'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.services', [])

.factory('myProperties', function () {

        var myProperties = [
        {
            'name': '3 Bedroom Fixer Upper',
            'city': 'Santa Rosa',
            'state': 'CA',
            'date_added': '2/3/14'
        },
        {
            'name': '2 Bedroom Condo',
            'city': 'Vallejo',
            'state': 'CA',
            'date_added': '4/10/20'
        },
        {
            'name': 'Apartment',
            'city': 'Salt Lake City',
            'state': 'UT',
            'date_added': '2/5/14'
        }
    ];
});

//controller.js

.controller('dashCtrl', function($scope, myProperties) {    

    $scope.myProperties = myProperties;

});
```

Bonus points: Does it make sense to write a unit test here? If so, what exactly should I test?

Comment: Stupide question but what if you put console.log just after settint myProperties in the controller scope?

Comment: console log displays as expected. No console errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need to return the array from the service, otherwise it remains internal to the scope of the service.

```
.factory('myProperties', function () {

        var myProperties = [
        {
            'name': '3 Bedroom Fixer Upper',
            'city': 'Santa Rosa',
            'state': 'CA',
            'date_added': '2/3/14'
        },
        {
            'name': '2 Bedroom Condo',
            'city': 'Vallejo',
            'state': 'CA',
            'date_added': '4/10/20'
        },
        {
            'name': 'Apartment',
            'city': 'Salt Lake City',
            'state': 'UT',
            'date_added': '2/5/14'
        }
    ];
    // Return the array here...
    return myProperties
});
```